# Ionic , angular , Show or disable a component within controller

Tags: angularjs, components, hide, ionic-framework

I have the following code. The following code displays 5  tag item.
What I wanted to do is when user click on any of the  tag item, it will be hidden or blank-out. But when I clicked on any of it, all the  tag item got blanked out instead of the item I selected. Can anyone give me some idea ?

```
<div data-ng-repeat="x in mylist">
   <a class="button" ng-click="hideme();" style="{{visibility}}">{{x}}</a> 
</div>  

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, chats) {      
    $scope.hideme = function(index, value) {
        $scope.visibility = "background-color: #000000 !important;";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you might want to change your object structure a bit. Remeber always have a dot (.) in your model value.

Try this.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in myList">
        <a href="" ng-click="hide(x)" ng-hide="x.hide">{{x.value}}</a>
    </div>
</div>

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myList = [{
        value: "a"
    }, {
        value: "b"
    }, {
        value: "c"
    }];

    $scope.hide = function(obj){
        obj.hide = true;
    }

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/0fa4wxeL/1/)

Comment: Hi Askash, your code works. But I don't quite understand why I can't have it this way.


`function myCtrl($scope){`
 `$scope.myList = [{ value: ["a","b","c"]}];`
    
    `$scope.hide = function(obj){`
     `obj.hide = true;`
    `}`
`}`

Comment: The reason is, if you inspect 'a', 'b' and 'c' you'll see angular has added a class call ng-scope for every repeat. It means any changes inside the scope will be applied to that model only. But, if you directly add it to the $scope object you the behaviour of all the models will change. You might want to learn how the scope works in angularjs.